# Android in app billing onPurchasesUpdate() giving previous purchase data instead of the last recent purchase

Tags: android, subscription

Firstly I bought yearly subscription then I downgrade it to monthly subscription (proration mode used deferred), now this time when I buy monthly subscription, it i.e onPurchasesUpdated callback method gives me purchase data of yearly subscription again instead of giving new purchase data i.e of monthly purchase, why it do so?

Comment: Do you mean that when you're downgrading from yearly to monthly subscription with the *deferred* proration mode, `onPurchasesUpdated()` returns the old product? And which Billing Library version do you use?

Comment: @VladGuriev Yes, it is 5.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue and fixed , it was related with `DEFERRED` proration mode, I changed it to `WITHOUT_PRORATION` and then it worked fine, it `(onPurchasesUpdate)` gave the latest purchases data instead of the old one